# Can't get value of input field when using ajax FormData() in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#color_changer_form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var colorCode = $('#color_code').val();
  var formData = new FormData(this)[0];
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{route('color.store')}}",
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="color_changer_form">
  <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code">
  <button type="submit" id="color_submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Change</button>
</form>
```

Controller snippet:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

When I try to get the whole form data using the jQuery AJAX `FormData()` method, I get an empty array.

In need to use this `FormData()` because in the near future I have to upload an image using the form data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the whole `formData` object

Change:

```
 var formData = new FormData(this)[0];
```

To

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
```

---

If there are no files involved it is simple to use `serialize()` also

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': "{{csrf_token()}}"
  },
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{route('color.store')}}",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }

});
```

> **Never** use `async:false`. it is a terrible practice and is deprecated

Comment: thanks for you great support. Please Clear me one thing. if here i upload a file or then how can i get the all the file value with file object, 

then what should i use 
 var formData = new FormData(this)[0];
or 
var formData = new FormData(this);

Comment: Why do you keep wanting to add the `[0]`?? Send the whole object! If there are file inputs it will include files also

Comment: yes .

if The Html Like This

<form action="" method="POST" id="color_changer_form">
 <input type="text" id="color_code" name="color_code">
<input type="file" id="file" name="image">
<button type="submit" id="color_submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Change</button>
</form>